# Why won't this mp4 play in a video-js <video> tag any longer

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video, video.js

I'm using ffmpeg to convert files to MP4.  I've made some modifications to the ffmpeg string but now it seems no matter what I use, the video won't play in an HTML5  tag (Chrome browser).  Normally, I just used "-vcodec libx264 -s 1280x720 -ar 22050".  When I try to load it in the video tag, I get the following error on http://family.gotsport.net/lmw/GotSport/videoPlayer.asp?WS=1&URL=/VideoFiles/2/4_70_highlight:

```
The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.
```

No matter what parameters I use (or don't use), it still won't play.  However, if you just call the url directly, it will play in Chrome (http://family.gotsport.net/videofiles/2/2_70_highlight.mp4).  I'm using the 7.0.0 version of video-js from their CDN (although older versions give the same result).

Video tag looks like:

```
<video id="myMovie" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" autoplay controls preload="auto" > 
    <source src="/VideoFiles/2/4_70_highlight.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

Here is the MediaInfo output from the file that won't play:

```
General
Complete name                            : E:\VideoFiles\2\2_70_highlight.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 5.87 MiB
Duration                                 : 27 s 60 ms
Overall bit rate                         : 1 820 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf58.29.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.1
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 27 s 60 ms
Bit rate                                 : 1 685 kb/s
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 29.970 (29970/1000) FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.061
Stream size                              : 5.44 MiB (93%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 158 r2984 3759fcb
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=12 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 27 s 22 ms
Duration_LastFrame                       : -6 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 22.05 kHz
Frame rate                               : 21.533 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 423 KiB (7%)
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1
```

Do you see anything that would keep this format from playing in an HTML5 video tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL is incorrect.

`4_70_highlight.mp4` doesn't seem to exist (404 error), and your direct URL testing used `2_70_highlight.mp4`.

Comment: OMG... can't tell you how long I've looked at that thinking all my adjustments to the ffmpeg parameters were off I never even thought to look at that.  Dude, I owe you many beers!

Comment: @Velocedge I recommend adding `-movflags +faststart` to your MP4 command so it can begin playing before it is completely downloaded.